# Persistence of function parameter between calls in Python function

Tags: python, parameter-passing, persistence

I don't understand the behavior of this code:

```
>>> def buggy(arg, result = []):
...     result.append(arg)
...     print(result)
...
>>> buggy('a')
['a']
>>> buggy('b')
['a', 'b']
```

It seems that `result` is persistent between calls of `buggy()`. Why is that? Local variables are not persistent in Python...

Comment: Because `result=[]` is part of the function _definition_, which is only executed _once_.